# cannot call str object with pymysql cursor.fetchall

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

i am trying to see if the user's input matches the string that i retrieved from a php database. I have retrieved the data and I can print it with print(i[random]), but when i try to compare the user's input with the englishWord = input("type answer", i[random]) statement, I get this error TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host="myhost",user="myname",password="mypassword",db="mydb")

myCursor = conn.cursor()

query = """SELECT russianWord, englishWord FROM words WHERE wordID = 1;"""

myCursor.execute(query)

records = myCursor.fetchall()

random = randint(0,1)

for i in records:
    if random == 0: 
        englishWord = input("type answer", i[random])
    else:
        russianWord = input("type ander", i[random])
```

Comment: You shadowed the builtin `input` with something else. Look for `input = ...` in your code and change it to something else

Comment: You did `input = ....` somewhere and overwrote the input function with a string...

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "somewhere" this is my whole code with the exception of the imports

Comment: Thank you for the response, but there is no input = in my code. what you see here is the whole program.